# Binding a TreeTableView

Tags: data-binding, binding, javafx, javafx-8

How can I bind [`TreeTableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html)? This gives me an error:

```
tblTreeView.rootProperty().bind(model.transactionProperty());
```

where `transactionProperty()`:

```
public SimpleListProperty<Document> transactionsProperty() {
        if(transactions == null){
            transactions = new SimpleListProperty<>();
        }
        return transactions;
    }
```

Comment: the root must be a TreeItem ...

Answer (score 0):

The [`rootProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html#rootProperty--) of a `TreeTableView` is an `ObjectProperty<TreeItem<S>>` (`S` The type of the TreeItem instances used in this TreeTableView)

```
TreeTableView<Document> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>();
ObjectProperty<TreeItem<Document>> rootProperty = treeTable.rootProperty();
```

it could be bound to an `ObservableValue<TreeItem<S>>`:

```
ObjectProperty<TreeItem<Document>> modelProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
rootProperty.bind(modelProperty);

modelProperty.set(myDocument); // will update the bound root property
```